# Create paragraph from a long String in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string

Here is an example of a long String :

```
Phasellus ligula est, lacinia dictum neque nec, venenatis malesuada lacus. Phasellus viverra odio vel tempor dapibus. Nunc ac sapien eu velit rutrum tristique. Fusce eu urna quis nunc consectetur blandit quis id metus. Donec id sodales augue, et ullamcorper nisl. Vestibulum venenatis sed leo id hendrerit. Aliquam eu eros scelerisque, molestie erat eget, vehicula augue. Phasellus eget orci eget quam ultricies adipiscing et a turpis. Ut malesuada eget erat malesuada suscipit. Donec eget nisl ac justo imperdiet laoreet eu vel erat. Nulla facilisi. In pretium facilisis porta. Quisque sollicitudin tortor at nulla vehicula, in congue magna semper. Praesent viverra mauris sit amet ipsum viverra, sit amet adipiscing tortor tincidunt. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Fusce at accumsan tellus, vel elementum mauris.
```

I would like to create a little function who cut the long string in some paragrah. (I don't want a paragrah for each new sentence)

How can i do this ?

Comment: did you try anything?

Comment: What defines the point at which you start a new paragraph?

Comment: In fact, i imagine that we start a new paragrah aleatory when a new sentence is detected

Comment: If you don't want one sentence by paragraph, what is the criteria for a new paragraph? Number of characters in the last one, ... ?

Comment: @wawanopoulos does that mean every sentence will be a new paragraph?

Comment: no @iJay, we can say that aleatory a paragrah must be created with 2 / 3 or 4 sentences.

Comment: @wawanopoulos So you seem to have a procedure in mind.  What, exactly are you having difficulty with?  Is it sentence boundary detection?  Random number generation?

Comment: Yes exactly this 2 things : Detect a new line and put each sentence into a paragrah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this function ...it should work as you expected

```
    function ConvertSentenceToParaGraph(sen) {
       var nS = '';
       var k = sen.split('.');
       for (var i = 0; i < k.length - 1; i++) {
          nS = nS + k[i] + ".";
          var ran = Math.floor((Math.random() * 2) + 4);
          if (i > 0 && i % ran == 0) {
             nS = nS + "\n\n";
          }
       }
       return nS;
    }
```

**Update:** Modified the code to work with random number from 4 to 5

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/X7ZAM/2/)

Comment: Works fine ! Finally, if i want to have a paragrah with 4 or 5 sentences, i must edit the line var ran = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 2); ???

Comment: if it works for you..plz upvote and mark as answer :)

Comment: Thanks. If i want the same code in Java, how can i modify this code ?

Comment: try implementing it in java....if u get stuck some where....post it on stack overflow as another question :) Good Luck